# about a sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have some table. They have information about students.Like basic student database.
I have course table : course_id , course_name

```
Student_course : student_num,course_id

student: name,student_num
```

A student can take more than 1 course.
Like
Student_Course tab:

```
Student_Num  Course 

1               2

1               3

2               2
```

My question is lets we have a course and it's id=2.I want to find the names of students who never take this course.
Is that possible with this tabs?If possible anyone help?

Comment: Please tag question with DB you're using eiter `mysql` or `Oracle`. Please post your tables schema exactly not like something. Please show some example data, and please show what have you tried. This looks like your homework. There is nothing wrong in looking for help but please show at least minimum of your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible (and easy). The `NOT IN` condition is the most likely candidate for a solution. If the `student_num` in `student_course` is constrained to `not null` (as it should be), your query may be as simple as

```
select student_name
from   student
where  student_id not in ( select student_id
                           from   student_course
                           where  course_id = 2
                         )
;
```

Now, before you turn in this homework, try to understand how it works. If any part of it is confusing, write back for clarification. For example, think about why this will fail if `student_id` in `student_course` may be `null`. How would you modify this solution to make it work even if `student_id` may be `null` in the `student_course` table? Just turning this in without any thought on your part will not benefit you in any way.

Comment: Uhh I was really easy.I had to think more time.Any way.
Can you give some details about your question :)
Thanks

Comment: @MetehanAytaç - if you have sample tables, change `student_id` to `null` in the `student_course` table, for a row where `course_id = 2`. Then run the query again. See what is happening? Try to figure out why. (Hint: `x NOT IN (a, b, c)` means `x != a AND x != b AND x != c` ... so what if you change `a` to `null`?)